# Launching the application in the background and keep dynamically added elements

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I recently started learning Xamarin Forms and am trying to write an Android app. It allows the user to add multiple timers and give each one a name. I faced two problems. When the application is minimized or the smartphone screen goes blank, the timer stops working. And if the application is closed and reopened, then the timers that the user added are not saved. How can I get the application to run continuously in the background and keep dynamically added elements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to save the state of the app and restore it when the app is closed or backgrounded

Answer (score 0):

You can try Background services:

Android - Creating Android Services:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/